# Form getting submitted even A4j validation fails +jsf

Tags: jsf

i am using a4j for checking username exists or not for onblur event
   it displays the error messages when user already exists but ,if i click on 
   submit button after displaying the error message it gets submitted
   when it comes to the required=true for inputtext it doesn't get submitted

required="true" validator="#{RegistrationBean.checkFirstName}">

public void checkFirstName(FacesContext facesContext, UIComponent component, Object value)
      {

```
    String name = (String) value;

     if(name.trim().length()==0){
         System.out.println("Name *******");

         String message = bundle.getString("Name_Required");
        FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().addMessage("Reg:firstName",
                new FacesMessage(FacesMessage.SEVERITY_ERROR, message,message));                


     }                  
     if(name.trim().equalsIgnoreCase("tom")){

         String message = bundle.getString("Name_exists");
        FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().addMessage("Reg:firstName",
                new FacesMessage(FacesMessage.SEVERITY_ERROR, message,message));                

    }

  }
```

could anyone suggest me where i went wrong

Answer (score 3):

With the JSF code, it would be easier to help you. So I suggest that you have something like that in your JSF page:

```
<h:inputText id="firstName" ... validator="#{aBean.checkFirstName}">
```

The problem on your Java code is that you do not throw any ValidatorException when an error occurs. Thus, your code must be:

```
public void checkFirstName(FacesContext facesContext, UIComponent component, Object value) {
    String name = (String) value;
    if ((name == null) || name.trim().length() == 0) {
        System.out.println("Name *******");
        String message = bundle.getString("Name_Required");
        throw new ValidatorException(new FacesMessage(FacesMessage.SEVERITY_ERROR, message, message)); // Throw the required error
    }
    if (name.trim().equalsIgnoreCase("tom")) {
        String message = bundle.getString("Name_exists");
        throw new ValidatorException(new FacesMessage(FacesMessage.SEVERITY_ERROR, message, message)); // Throw the already exist error
    }
}
```

This way, if the value filled in this field is empty or already exists, a ValidatorException will be thrown, the user will get an error message (do not forget to add the `<h:messages/>` or `<h:message/>` component in your form), and the form will not be submitted!

Comment: If your problem is solved, please select my answer as the correct answer (if it is the case) (click on the icon below the 0 on the left)